How does this Business Central API code work calling Record.Insert twice?
I'm trying to understand how the Microsoft Business Central APIs work. I'm looking at the Vendors API (APIV2 - Vendors). In the OnInsertRecord trigger, it appears to me the record is inserted twice if the vendor doesn't already exist and once if the vendor does exist.
trigger OnInsertRecord(BelowxRec: Boolean): Boolean
    var
        Vendor: Record Vendor;
        VendorRecordRef: RecordRef;
    begin
        Vendor.SetRange("No.", Rec."No.");
        if not Vendor.IsEmpty() then
            Rec.Insert();

        Rec.Insert(true);

        ...

        exit(false);
    end;

I don't understand how that second Rec.Insert(true) can run without an error. Either the record already existed when the trigger ran or it was just inserted by the trigger, right?
The documentation for Record.Insert() states (because the return value was omitted) "If customer 1120 already exists, then a run-time error occurs." Does Record.Insert(Boolean) not work the same way? If the record already exists will Business Central update it or just skip the operation?
What am I missing? Do I not understand how the trigger works? Am I missing something about how the Record.Insert() methods work?

Copilot, ChatGPT, and Gemini are all telling me that the argument to Record.Insert(Boolean) controls whether the method should overwrite any existing record. This is not true, is it?

I think I finally see what is going on here. My confusion was partially in how I read the condition and first Rec.Insert(). That code is not inserting a record if it does not already exist, it is calling Rec.Insert() if the record does already exist.
Since Rec.Insert() will be called if a vendor with the same number does already exist, this call to Rec.Insert() will always result in an error. It looks like this is by design, I assume to stop processing the request and return an error if the vendor already exists.
If a vendor with the same number does not already exist, the vendor record will be inserted by Record.Insert(true). We can only get this far if the vendor does not already exist.
This code is rather hard to understand but I believe that is what is happening.

Yes, you are right. The first Insert under the condition is just the way of throwing an error if the record already exists. It may look a bit confusing, but they did it to force the BC runtime to return the native error instead of composing a synthetic error in client code. Regarding the Insert(true) - insert never overwrites an existing record. The Boolean parameter tells whether the OnInsert trigger in the table should be executed or not.
